# Is it possible to have a label display text from the current active textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

I am making a C# Windows Form project in Visual Studio 2019. I currently have 40 textboxes that users have to fill in. These textboxes are quite small, which is why at the top of the program I created a large label. I was wondering if it's possible in C# to display the text from the active textbox that the user is filling in within this label box.
I'm not sure if this piece of information would have any baring on this process, but once the user fills in the correct information in the current said textbox, it automatically disables it and moves on to the next one.

So for an example:
[image: Label at top, textboxes below]

Whenever the user enters anything in any of those textboxes, the active textbox text displays at the top (in the label).

Comment: Take a look at the events `TextChanged`, `LostFocus`, or `Validating` - I think `TextChanged` is the event you are after. It will fire everytime a user changes any part of the text box

Comment: Aside: It might make more sense to the user to have a single text box at the top of the window with a label to its left indicating which "target" is selected. Use a radio button or other appropriate control to select the "target". Copy the text box contents to a label on the target as appropriate, e.g. character-by-character or when the value is terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form's constructor, add event handlers for the `TextChanged` and `Enter` events of all your TextBoxes. It should look something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (var textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        textBox.TextChanged += TextBoxes_TextChanged;
        textBox.Enter += TextBoxes_TextChanged;
    }
}
```

Note that `this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` will only work if the TextBoxes are placed directly on the form. If they're placed in another container (e.g., GroupBox or Panel), you may use the following instead:

```
theOtherContainer.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
```

Then, you can change the Label's text using the following event handler:

```
private void TextBoxes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    label1.Text = textBox.Text;
}
```

You could also add event handlers for the `Leave` event in order to clear the text when the cursor leaves a certain TextBox. To do that, just add the following line in the `foreach` loop above:

```
textBox.Leave += (o, e) =>  label1.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: If you have TextBoxes in multiple containers, then write a RECURSIVE function to find all the TextBoxes.

Comment: If I was to use this method, the one thing I'm confused about is the foreach loop. With the example you posted, you used TextBoxes_TextChanged for both lines of code. Just so I'm clear of what I should do, I should replace those lines with the tb1_TextChanged; tb2_TextChanged, etc.? The 40 textboxes I have created were labled tb1, tb2 and on up, but I didn't put them in an array. They were created individually and not in a groupbox.

Comment: @ReneeToto **NO**. The whole point of the loop is so that you don't have to do the same thing for the 40 TextBoxes manually. The reason why I used `TextBoxes_TextChanged` twice was because it's used for both the `TextChanged` and `Enter` event (admittedly, that event hander could use a better name though).

Comment: I think that is the part I am confused about. When you say the event handler, so far on all of the 40 textboxes I have those setup with event handlers for TextChanged already. On each one, do I have to add an event handler for Enter as well? And it says TextBoxes doesn't exist so when I created: public EventHandler TextBoxes_TextChanged { get; set; } that removes the errors on that side, but it does not display the desired result.

Comment: @ReneeToto If you already have an event handler for all TextBoxes **and** they all do the same thing, then you should move that code into `TextBoxes_TextChanged` from the code in my answer (they can all share the same event handler as shown above). If they do different things, you may keep them and you can still use the same code in my answer because events can have more than one event handler. Just make sure that you use the right container as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netcore-3.1) event to accomplish this. The first parameter will be the `TextBox` which fired the event, so you can cast it from an `object` to a `TextBox`.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    label.Text = txt.Text;
}
```

You can use the designer to hook up all of your `TextBox` instances to that one event by selecting them all at once then going to the event page of their properties window.

You can use the same event handler and the [`Enter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter) event so that when you enter the next `TextBox` the `Label` changes.

One thing to be aware of with this approach is that `TextChanged` will trigger for anything that causes the `TextBox.Text` to change, and not just keyboard inputs.